How do we differentiate the function $f(x) = (3x^{3} - 4x^{2} + 8x)\sqrt{6x^{2} + 3x}$?

I hope someone can help me with this derivative, I have already made this: 
At the first part, I did not have issues with the root derivative and then multiply it with $(3x^3-4x^2+8x)$, that part is clear. But I have issues multiplying the derivative which is $(9x^2-8x+8) \times (\sqrt{ 6x^2 + 3x})$, how can I multiply with a root, I used a calculator and it gave me this:  but it cannot explain to me how the computer made the product, thank you for your help guys, and sorry for my bad English.

Please write the images into the text. Otherwise, good question.

Please edit your question to remove the images and pasted math, and instead use MathJax to express all of the math in the question.

Note that
$$
\sqrt{6x^{2}+3x}\cdot(9x^{2}-8x+8)\cdot\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{6x^{2}+3x}}{\sqrt{6x^{2}+3x}}\bigg)=\frac{(6x^{2}+3x)(9x^{2}-8x+8)}{\sqrt{6x^{2}+3x}}.
$$
This is how the square root in the numerator seems to disappear.

Note: you can write multiplication as \cdot to get $\cdot$ or \times to get $\times$.
